# How can I check if my parameter is null in the script when it's a list that allow multiple values?

Tags: sql, parameters, null, birt

I created non-required parameters in a cascading parameters : 
[image]

The month-opt parameter isn't required AND is allow multiple values.

I used this parameter in the query, so I created a script :

```
if(params["MONTH-OPT"].value != null && params["MONTH-OPT"].value != ""){
    this.queryText = this.queryText + " AND MONTH IN (" + params["MONTH-OPT"].value.join("," ) +") ";
}
```

My issue is : if a user select a Null Value :

[image]

Then, I had an issue :

```
Cannot get the result set metadata.
    org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object.
SQL error #1:Incorrect syntax near ')'.
 ;
    java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near ')'. (Element ID:18061)
```

Seems like the test about the null is not correct because it bypass the check. If I don't allow the multiple values, it's working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on : https://fr.scribd.com/document/15350321/BIRT-Multi-Value-Cascading-Parameters

The fix can be (I think it's not the best...) :

```
if(params["MONTH-OPT"].value != null ){
    var monthOptionNullValue = params["MONTH-OPT"].toString();
    if( monthOptionNullValue != null && monthOptionNullValue != ""){
        this.queryText = this.queryText + " AND MONTH IN (" + params["MONTH-OPT"].value.join("," ) +") ";
    }
}
```

Thanks to srp for the help

Answer (score 0):

when you are using IN operator, it is required to always have some value in the brackets.

```
 INVALID SYNTAX 
 select * from table where id in ()


 Valid Syntax 
   select * from table where id in (null)
   or 
   select * from table where id in ('')
```

etc 
Make changes in your code to pass null values to resolve the issue.

You can use a simple if condition in  your script

```
if  params["MONTH-OPT"].value =  Null
   select * from table
else 
  select * from table where id in (1, 2)  etc
```

Comment: Yes, however, my question was more about How can I check if my parameter is null in the script when it's a list that allow multiple values? Because, by passing null or '' will return no value from my query and I want all the values

Comment: I tried : "params["MONTH-OPT"].value != null", but, the "Null Value" seems to have another value. So, I tried params["MONTH-OPT"].value != "Null Value" and it's not working neither. Thanks for your help

Comment: Why dont you use a simple if condition your script .

Comment: :) That's what I tried... but I didn't find the good condition (yet?)

Comment: Do you have multiple values for  month i.e within the   IN operator ?

Comment: Check this  https://interprosoft.com/maximotimes/maximo/tips-tricks/quick-tip-check-for-null-with-birt-reports-in-expression-data-binding/